# Can not run android 12 on emulator

Tags: android-studio, gradle, emulation, android-12, avd-manager

I got the error in Android Studio:
The emulator process for avd pixel_5_api_31 has terminated

[image: my Error]

I did install Android-12 on the android studio's emulator but I fail.
I know why there is this problem?
1- low space
2- problem in config

but I don't problem with the list, so I can't run android studio's emulator for android 12.

**My Android IDE version**
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 1

---

**My Gradle**

```
 plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    }
    
    android {
        namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
        compileSdk 32
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
            minSdk 31
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
```

Comment: same issue on Intelij Idea and Android studio latest version.

Comment: @Eng - yes, I did but get an error same ->  "The emulator process for avd pixel_5_api_31 has terminated"

Comment: @Eng- I checked "android studio - Dolphin (2021.3.1) Canary 1" and "android studio - Chipmunk (2021.2.1) Beta 1"